# Why does fabs return integer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

When I do the following, the output is an integer value:

```
double myvar = fabs(-5.01);
NSLog(@"%.f", myvar);
```

Should it be 5.01?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.` (with no number after it) in `"%.f"` means format with a precision of 0 (which for floats, means round to the nearest integer). You probably just want "%f"

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ for a description of the format specifiers (I gather the `NSLog` format specifiers are a superset of the `printf` ones)

Answer (score 0):

What is the output? Have you tried `@"%f"`? But yes. It should return 5.01. There's a chance the precision may be off since it's floating point, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
double myvar = fabs(-5.01);
NSLog(@"%.2f", myvar);
```

As `%.f` means that after `.` no value must be there so if you want 2 decimal points you need to write `%.2f`

hAPPY cODING...